# How can I count the number of times each edge is traveled given a trajectory using SQL?

Tags: sql, algorithm, graph

The trajectory is represented as a table like the following, you can think of it as some object walks in a graph following the edges `B->A->C->A->B`.

```
+ ---- + ---- +
| time | node |
+ ---- + ---- +
| 1    | B    |
| 2    | A    |
| 3    | C    |
| 4    | A    |
| 5    | B    |
+ ---- + ---- +
```

I want to count the number of times each (directed) edge is traveled using SQL, how should I do this?

---

Right now what I did is duplicating each row with `time+1` like this

```
+ ---- + ---- +
| time | node |
+ ---- + ---- +
| 1    | B    |
| 2    | B    |
| 2    | A    |
| 3    | A    |
| 3    | C    |
| 4    | C    |
| 4    | A    |
| 5    | A    |
| 5    | B    |
| 6    | B    |
+ ---- + ---- +
```

then I group by `time` and aggregate the `node` as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql#d-return-news-articles-with-related-tags), and I can get something like

```
+ ---- + ----- +
| edge | count |
+ ---- + ----- +
| B,A  | 1     |
| A,C  | 1     |
| C,A  | 1     |
| A,B  | 1     |
+ ---- + ----- +
```

However the problem is, I need to run it on some distributed environment, where it seems the order of group by results are not guaranteed, so sometimes `B->A` and `A->B` will both come out as `A,B`, which is not what I want since the edges are considered directed.

What can I do to preserve the order?
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider adding your queries to the question.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using a window function:

```
select node, next_node, count(*)
from (
  select node, lead(node) over (order by time) as next_node
  from nodes
) t
where next_node is not null
group by node, next_node
order by node;
```

You didn't state your DBMS, but the above is standard SQL without any product specific syntax.

Online example: http://rextester.com/WUVB19983

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand why duplicating the rows is necessary. Have you considered something like the following?

```
SELECT t1.node + ',' + t2.node, count(*)
FROM mytable t1 inner join mutable t2
    on t2.time = t1.time+1
GROUP BY t1.node + ',' + t2.node
```

Comment: This will fail if there are gaps in the `time` column (plus: in "SQL" `||` is the operator to concatenate strings)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The original question also referred to time+1, so I assumed it was safe. The original question linked to Microsoft documentation (even thought SQL Server isn't explicitly tagged), and + is a valid concatenation in SQL Server.